# Neo4j Desktop: how to redirect where graph apps are prepared on first start?

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-desktop

I installed Neo4j Desktop using: "neo4j-desktop-offline-1.0.22-setup.exe".
The computer has Java 10 with a server folder: "C:\Program Files\Java\jre-10.0.1\bin\server" 
The JAVA_HOME environment variable is set to "C:\Program Files\Java\jre-10.0.1"

Steps to Reproduce Error

1. Start Neo4j Desktop [for the first time].
2. Neo4j Desktop displays status messages, ending with: "Getting ready, please wait" and "Preparing Graph Apps". [An independent test on a non-work computer showed that Neo4j Desktop is trying to create a directory called ".Neo4jDesktop" in the Windows user profile directory. It contains 343 MB of files.]
3. Neo4j Desktop displays this error message:

"Initialization error: Error: ENOSPC: no space left on device, write"

(The above is the exact error message, character-for-character.)

4. Neo4j Desktop freezes, and I got an email from the company's network:

"You have exceeded 100% of the quota threshhold for your PND folder on (Drive H:). The quota limit is 750.00 MB, and 749.97 MB currently is in use (99% of limit)."

5. On closing Neo4j Desktop, it releases the space.

In our company, the [Windows user profile directory, including the] "My Documents" folder, is mapped to a server folder rather than the local drive. I cannot control that or get a larger space allocation. How can I get Neo4j Desktop to install its graph apps [in the ".Neo4jDesktop" folder] to the local drive, which has 70 GB free?

This is my first question. I ask the community to create a Neo4j Desktop tag. Neo4j Desktop is new with Neo4j 3.3.5. It is the developers’ mission control console for the Neo4j environment and graph analytics.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the neo4j config file for your Desktop Project to specify the desired location of the data directory.

1. Open the Neo4j Desktop, and select the Project.
2. Click the `Stop` button (if available, which indicates the DB is running).
3. Click the `Manage` button.
4. Click the dropdown menu button to the right of `Open Folder`.
5. Select the `Configuration` option.
6. Use a text editing app to edit the `neo4j.conf` file.
7. Change this line:

   ```
   #dbms.directories.data=data
   ```

   to this (if you wanted the data in the `C:\MyNeo4jDBData\databases\graph.db` directory):

   ```
   dbms.directories.data=C:/MyNeo4jDBData/
   ```

   Note that you use forward slashes ('/') in the config file instead of backward slashes. Also, you can change the `graph.db` portion of the path to some other name by uncommenting and setting this line appropriately: `#dbms.active_database=graph.db`.
8. Save your changes.
9. Click the Arrow icon to start the DB.
10. If you see a password error, click the `Ask Me Later` button.
11. Click the `Open Browser` button.
12. Login with the default password ("neo4j") and set the new password.
13. You should now be running with a new empty DB in the desired location.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot change the neo4j config file (neo4j.conf) for your Desktop Project to specify the desired location of the data directory, because it is not created during the failed installation. l searched local hard disk and the server-mapped folder for neo4j.conf. If the installer program had completed its installation (which includes starting Neo4j Desktop for the first time) maybe would have created neo4j.conf file. I need a way to make the installer program install to a location I specify, instead of the default location (a server folder with to little room for Neo4j Desktop.

Comment: You may want to create a new [Neo4j Desktop issue](https://github.com/neo4j-apps/neo4j-desktop/issues) to make this feature request.

Comment: Per Cybersam, I have created a Neo4j Desktop issue on Github to make an enhancement request: "Allow user to specify where Neo4j Desktop creates the '.Neo4jDesktop' folder".